# looping through DOM / mootools sortables

Tags: serialization, loops, mootools, mootools-sortable

I can't seem to get a handle on my list of sortables. They are a list of list elements, each with a

form inside, which I need to get the values from.

```
Sortables.implement({
    serialize: function(){
        var serial = [];
        this.list.getChildren().each(function(el, i){
            serial[i] = el.getProperty('id');
        }, this);
        return serial;
    }
});



var sort = new Sortables('.teams', {
        handle: '.drag-handle',
        clone: true,
        onStart: function(el) {
            el.fade('hide');
        },
        onComplete: function(el) {
            //go go gadget go
            order = this.serialize();
            alert(order);
            for(var i=0; i<order.length;i++) {
                if (order[i]) {
                    //alert(order[i].substr(5, order[i].length));
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

the sortables list is then added to a list in a loop with `sort.addItems(li);` . But when I try to get the sortables outside of the sortables onComplete declaration, js says this.list is undefined.

---

**Approaching the problem from another angle:**

Trying to loop through the DOM gives me equally bizarre results. Here are the firebug console results for some code:

```
var a = document.getElementById('teams').childNodes;
var b = document.getElementById('teams').childNodes.length;

try {
    console.log('myVar: ', a);
    console.log('myVar.length: ', b);
} catch(e) {
    alert("error logging");
}
```

**Hardcoding one li element into the HTML (rather than being injected via JS) changes length == 1, and allows me to access that single element, leading me to believe that accessing injected elements via the DOM is the problem (for this method)**

[image: firebug]

Trying to get the objects with `document.getElementById('teams').childNodes[i]` returns undefined.

thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1):

not sure why this would fail, i tried it in several ways and it all works

http://www.jsfiddle.net/M7zLG/ test case along with html markup

here is the source that works for local refernece, using the native built-in .serialize method as well as a custom one that walks the dom and gets a custom attribute rel, which can be your DB IDs in their new order (I tend to do that)

```
var order = []; // global

var sort = new Sortables('.teams', {
    handle: '.drag-handle',
    clone: true,
    onStart: function(el) {
        el.fade('hide');
    },
    onComplete: function(el) {
        //go go gadget go
        order = this.serialize();
    }
});

var mySerialize = function(parentEl) {
    var myIds = [];
    parentEl.getElements("li").each(function(el) {
        myIds.push(el.get("rel"));
    });

    return myIds;
};

$("saveorder").addEvents({
    click: function() {
        console.log(sort.serialize());
        console.log(order);
        console.log(mySerialize($("teams")));
    }
});
```